# Firebase push JSON Object to JSON Array

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have created document in Firebase using:

```
'tasks': [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'type': TaskType.ImportantAndNotUrgent.toTypeName(),
      'name': 'Just added this',
      'deadline': DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1)).toIso8601String(),
      'tags': [
        {
          'id': 1,
          'name': 'addTask method'
        },
      ],
    }
  ],
```

I want to push new object to 'tasks' array, so it would look like:

```
'tasks': [
    {
      //First object
    },
    {
      //Second object
    },
  ],
```

I've got DocumentReference to this document, but I don't know how to push new value. Calling update() method replaces 'tasks' instead of pushing to it.

My code:

```
Future addTask(String uid, TaskModel task) async {
var taskCollection = firestore.collection('usersData')
    .doc(uid).collection('tasks').doc('ImportantAndNotUrgent');
print("Adding task");
taskCollection.update({
  'tasks':
    {
      'id': 1,
      'type': TaskType.ImportantAndNotUrgent.toTypeName(),
      'name': 'Just added this',
      'deadline': DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1)).toIso8601String(),
      'tags': [
        {
          'id': 1,
          'name': 'addTask method'
        },
      ],
    }
})
    .then((value) => print("Successfully added task"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add task: $error"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `arrayUnion`, like this:

```
 .update({
  'tasks': FieldValue.arrayUnion([{
      'id': 1,
      'type': TaskType.ImportantAndNotUrgent.toTypeName(),
      'name': 'Just added this',
      'deadline': DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1)).toIso8601String(),
      'tags': [
        {
          'id': 1,
          'name': 'addTask method'
        },
      ],
    }]),       
   })
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it worked. Do you know how to add more objects to 'tags'?

Comment: `FieldValue.arrayUnion([{tag1 data}, {tag2 data} , {tag3 data}])`